# Equation of motion by Runge-Kutta continuation method in Matlab

Tags: matlab, equation, motion, runge-kutta

- Equation of motion is given by:

[image: equation]
,where m, b are stationary values of mass and damping. The time varying term f(t) is excitation power and q(t) is generalized displacement.

- I solved that:

[image]

[image]

- And I should to solve in MatLab via [t,x]=ode23('rightside',tspan,x0).
- f(t) and k(t) I solved in complex numbers via Fourier series like that in Matlab:

*% complex fourier series for f(t)*

```
ft=zeros(size(t)); 
for j=1:2*N+1
n= j-(N+1);    
if n==0
   f(j)=f0/2;
else
   f(j)=f0*( (exp(-i*n*2*pi)*(i*2*pi*n+1)-1)/(4*pi^2*n^2));   
   end
ft=ft+f(j)*exp(i*n*om*t);
end
```

*% complex fourier series for k(t)*

```
kt=k0*ones(size(t)); 
for s=1:2*N+1
    n= s-(N+1);    
    if n==0
       c(s)=k0;
    else
       c(s)=i*(k0+ktyl)/n/pi*(1-cos(n*pi));     
    end
    kt=kt+c(s)*exp(i*n*om*t);
end
```

- And we know:

```
T=30;
dt=0.01;
t=0:0.01:5*T;
k0=1e6;
om=2*pi/T;
ktyl=0.5e6;
N=10;
m=1;
ks=1e4;
D=0.01;
OMG=sqrt(ks/m);
b=2*D*OMG*m;
f0=100;
```

Thank you.

- **It should be similar princip like that:**

```
function v=prst1(t,y)
global m b k Om D F omeg
v(1)=....;
v(2)=y(1);
v=v(:);
```

- **and:**

```
global m b k Om D F omeg
m=1;
b=10;
k=1000;
F=10;
Om=sqrt(k/m);
omeg=1*Om;
D=b/(2*Om*m);
x0=[0;0];
[t,x]=ode23('prst1',0:0.01:10,x0);
plot(t,x)
```

- **BUT I don't how to get there f(t) and k(t).**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I should to solve in MatLab via [t,x]=ode23('rightside',tspan,x0) this

Comment: y'(1)=1/m*[f(t)-b*y(1)-k(t)*y(2)]

Comment: y'(2)=y(1)     and with f(t) and k(t)

Comment: And I don't know how to type this code and program 'rightside'

Comment: have you tried reading the documentation for ode23 ? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode23.html ...

Comment: I edited, pls look at it. Thx and I read help in Matlab.